# Unexpected result with F# type check

Tags: f#

Why are these 2 functions (f1 and f2) returning different results?

```
let f1<'t>() = if typeof<byte[]> = typeof<'t> then printfn "Is Byte Array" else printfn "Is Not Byte Array"

let f2<'t>() =
    match box Unchecked.defaultof<'t> with
    | :? (byte[]) -> printfn "Is Byte Array" 
    | _ -> printfn "Is Not Byte Array"

f1<byte[]>();;
Is Byte Array

f2<byte[]>();;
Is Not Byte Array
```

EDIT

If using Unchecked.defaultof<> is not, is there a way to implement f4 to obtain the same output as f3 (i.e. using pattern matching in place of typeof<>)?

```
let f3<'t>() = 
    if typeof<'t> = typeof<byte[]> then printfn "byte[]" 
    elif typeof<'t> = typeof<int> then printfn "int" 
    elif typeof<'t> = typeof<WHATEVER> then printfn "WHATEVER" 
    ...
    else printfn "Not recognized"

let f4<'t>() =
    match ????? with
    | :? (byte[]) -> printfn "byte[]" 
    | :? int -> printfn "int" 
    | :? WHATEVER -> printfn "WHATEVER" 
    ...
    | _ -> printfn "Not recognized"
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `Unchecked.defaultof<'t>` always returns `null` for reference types.

```
> Unchecked.defaultof<byte[]>;;
val it: byte array = <null>

> Unchecked.defaultof<int>;;
val it: int = 0

> Unchecked.defaultof<string>;;
val it: string = <null>

> Unchecked.defaultof<int * bool>;;
val it: int * bool = <null>

> Unchecked.defaultof<bool>;;
val it: bool = false
```

That's what the "unchecked" part is supposed to convey. This value is not checked for any sort of correctness/validity. If you use these functions, you better know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Fyodor's answer, the null value carries no runtime type information, which means that once it's boxed, it essentially has no type. You can see this without even calling `Unchecked.defaultof`:

```ml
let f3() =
    let x : byte[] = null
    match box x with
    | :? (byte[]) -> printfn "Is Byte Array" 
    | _ -> printfn "Is Not Byte Array"
    
f3 ();;
Is Not Byte Array
```

In fact, to my surprise, `null` won't even match with type `obj`, even though the compiler generates a warning saying it "always" will:

```ml
let f4() =
    let x : obj = null
    match x with
    | :? obj -> printfn "Is Object"   // warning FS0067: This type test or downcast will always hold
    | _ -> printfn "Is Not Object"
    
f4 ();;
Is Not Object
```

LOL. This is a compiler bug, but probably not one that needs an urgent fix.

If you decompile the IL back to C#, it's easier to see what's happening:

```cs
object obj = null as object;
if (obj != null)
{
    // printfn "Is Object"
}
else
{
    // printfn "Is Not Object"
}
```

That test is clearly never going to succeed.

Comment: Yeah, the fact that `null` doesn't match `:? obj` is expected, but the compiler definitely shouldn't warn that it always does!